# how to clip pandas for a multiple column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the df:

```
{'Type 1': {1: 123.0,
  2: 123.0,
  3: 123.0,
  4: 123.0,
  5: 123.0,
  6: 45.0,
  7: 45.0,
  8: 45.0,
  9: 45.0,
  10: 9.5,
  11: 9.5,
  12: 9.5,
  13: 2.34,
  14: 2.34,
  15: 2.34},
 'Type 2': {1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: -90,
  4: -90,
  5: -90,
  6: -90,
  7: -90,
  8: -270,
  9: -270,
  10: -270,
  11: -270,
  12: 180,
  13: 180,
  14: 181,
  15: 181},
 'Type 3': {1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 55,
  6: 55,
  7: 55,
  8: 55,
  9: 55,
  10: 9,
  11: 9,
  12: 3,
  13: 3,
  14: 3,
  15: 3},
 'Type 4': {1: 5.0,
  2: 5.0,
  3: 5.0,
  4: 5.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 123.0,
  7: 12.0,
  8: 23.0,
  9: 16.0,
  10: 3.14,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 18.0},
 'Type 5': {1: 65536,
  2: 65536,
  3: 65536,
  4: 65536,
  5: 78888888,
  6: 665,
  7: 665,
  8: 665,
  9: 665,
  10: 665,
  11: 665,
  12: 665,
  13: 665,
  14: 665,
  15: 665},
 'Type 6': {1: 3.4124,
  2: 3.4124,
  3: 3.4124,
  4: 3.4124,
  5: 3.4124,
  6: 3.4124,
  7: 3.4124,
  8: 3.4124,
  9: 3.4124,
  10: 3.4124,
  11: 3.4124,
  12: 3.4124,
  13: 3.4124,
  14: 3.4124,
  15: 3.4124},
 'Type 7': {1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 2,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 10,
  11: 10,
  12: 9,
  13: 9,
  14: -5,
  15: -5},
 'Type 8': {1: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  2: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  3: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  4: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  5: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  6: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  7: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  8: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  9: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  10: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  11: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  12: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  13: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  14: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1',
  15: 'convert the string to 0 and non-zero value to 1'},
 'Type 9': {1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 0,
  9: 0,
  10: 8,
  11: 8,
  12: 0,
  13: 0,
  14: 45,
  15: 45}}
```

each column in the dataframe has a lower and an upper limit as mentioned in the below list

eg:

```
lower_limit = [3,-90,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]          #Type 1 lower limit is 3...
upper_limit = [100,90,50,100,65535,3,1,1,1]  #Type 1 upper limit is 100...

lower_limit = pd.Series(lower_limit)
upper_limit = pd.Series(upper_limit)

df.clip(lower_limit, upper_limit, axis = 1)
```

But this returns every element as nan

whereas the expected result is to clip each column based on the upper limit and lower limit mentioned in the list...

Using for loop, I was able to make the necessary change, but it was extremely slower when the size of df is huge

I understand clipping is the faster way to make the changes to df but it doesnt work as expected, I am doing some mistake in it and advice if any other alternative ways of clipping the columns in a faster way?

Comment: So are you expecting an entire row to be clipped if any one column value is outside it's respectively range?

Comment: `Type 8` column in your dataframe has values of type string i.e `dtype` of column is `object`..so basically this column cant be clipped but you are defining the lower and upper limit for the same which doesn't make sense. How do you want to handle such case?

Comment: @Creekgeek:Yes I want the entire column to be clipped based on the limits...

Comment: @Shubham Sharma: ok in that case, can we skip the particular column alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html), `lower` and `upper` must be `float` or `array-like`, not `Series`.

You could do

```
lower_limit = [3,-90,0,0,0,1,0,'',0]          #Type 1 lower limit is 3...
upper_limit = [100,90,50,100,65535,3,1,'',1]  #Type 1 upper limit is 100...

df.clip(lower_limit, upper_limit, axis = 1)
```

but column `Type 8` is as string so you'd get an empty column with clip, you can fix with

```
lower_limit = [3,-90,0,0,0,1,0,df['Type 8'].min(),0]
upper_limit = [100,90,50,100,65535,3,1,df['Type 8'].max(),1]
```

Comment: It works, for valid columns.. if at all the dtype of a column is object, is it possible to skip the particular column?

Comment: Has `Type 8` column, or other string columns in your df, multiple values or is it a unique string for the entire df? In this case, you can use `df['Type 8'].unique()[0]` for both upper and lower.

Comment: It will be multiple strings, sometimes there comes a junk character in other columns like '45ad' in Type 1 as well... right now, correcting those manually to zero...

Comment: I edited the answer. This should work for all multiple values string columns.